# Find the two values of k for $y=e^{kx}$ so that $2y''-y'-15y=0$ and show that it works.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I figured out that $k=3$ or $k=-\frac52$.

So I got $y=e^{kx}$ or $y=e^{-\frac52x}$.

I'm stuck on showing that these values work.

Would I have to take the derivatives of the function with the found $k$ value in it and plug into the $2y''-y'-15y=0$ and then solve for $x$?

If so, would I then plug in the value of $x$ into $y=e^{3x}$ and do the same process again to show that it equals $0$?

Comment: The questions wanted you to find the K values and show that the K values lead to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $2y''-y'-15 = e^{kx}(2k^2 - k - 15)$. Can you continue?

Comment: Yeah I found that K=3 and K=-5/2 but I don't know how to show that they are the right solutions. Would I have to solve for x once I find the K's

Comment: No, you don't have to. $k$ would be enough.

Comment: Well he still has to substitute the solution into the differential equation to show that it is satisfied, even if he solved for k already

Comment: so If I took y=e^3x and took the first and second derivative and plugged it into the equation I would get 0-e^(3x)(3)-(15)e^(3x)=0 and then would you say that x=0

Answer (score 0):

You have find two solutions of the differential equation. Since it is linear and second-order you have as general solution a linear combination of the two finded solutions, i.e.:
$$
y=a\cdot e^{-5x/2}+b\cdot e^{3x}
$$